# How set-up a domain?

Tags: php, apache, networking, web, dns

I've a problem with my domain.
Recently I've purchased **mydomain.com** and I've configured DNS, by the control panel of my registrar, in record A the **"*"** and **"www"** point to my server ip. *(It's a home server with Win 7 Pro)*.
The nameservers are default of my domain registrar.
Now, I use AMMPS, and I've manually configured virtual host in httpd.conf & httpd-vhosts.conf, and the situation is this:

**In httpd.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName localhost
ServerAlias localhost 127.0.0.1
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/cgi-bin/"
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/"
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache/logs/error.err"
CustomLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache/logs/access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**In httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
#DO NOT EDIT, CREATED BY AMPPS


#### mydomain.com VirtualHost ####

<VirtualHost *:80>
<Directory "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/mydomain.com">
    Options FollowSymLinks Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    allow from All
</Directory>
ServerName mydomain.com
ServerAlias www.mydomain.com
DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/www/mydomain.com"
ErrorLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache/logs/mydomain.com_error.err"
CustomLog "C:/Program Files (x86)/Ampps/apache/logs/mydomain.com_access.log" combined
</VirtualHost>


####################################
```

Now it's all right because when i type in the browser "localhost" it shows the folder www of AMPPS, and when I type www.mydomain.com it shows content of www/mydomain.com

But, If I type in the browser mydomain.com **without prefix www.**, it shows the courtesy page of my domain registrar.

How I can fix this?

Comment: So you've pointed `*.mydomain.com` and `www.mydomain.com` (which, BTW, is redundant) to your IP, but what about `mydomain.com` (no leading `.`)?

Comment: @deceze right, and how can I fix?